# change permission using .bat file in window server 2008 r2

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, batch-file

I'm doing the permissions in Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm learning to use a batch file to do this quickly, but it's not doing the right thing that I want. This is the code of the simple .bat file

```
icacls D:\Test2 /grant p5:(wa)
```

This is the display:

[image: http://i1090.photobucket.com/albums/i374/huydo155/i1_zps9f29cef5.png]

User p5 has no permissions except "special permissions", and in the advanced menu, it displays:

[image: http://i1090.photobucket.com/albums/i374/huydo155/i2_zps63f8167b.png]

It's the right permission that I want, and I'm trying permissions like

```
icacls D:\Test2 /grant p5:(d,m)
```

It's just displayed like in picture 1.

**My Question: i want when i set, permission gonna is "this folder, subfolders and files" and the permission outsite (like in pic 1) must be set. how i can do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but in the first case, you are granting user "p5" JUST the ability to write attributes.  In the second case, you are granting rights JUST to delete or modify. In neither case are you granting read and/or file-scan rights, which would seem very odd to me.  So you see the "special permissions".

I am not sure exactly what you want to get, but you should be giving read, file-scan, and then the "write"-related rights if you want the user to be able to delete files or change their attributes.

Comment: i want when i set, permission when is "this folder, subfolders and files" and the permission outsite (like in pic 1) must be set. how i can do?

Comment: As I stated above, it's a multi-step process.  To have it not only affect the existing subfolders and files, but future ones, you must turn on "inheritance" first. Then apply the permissions.

Comment: if i turn "inheritance" on, the permission at farther folder and child folder gonna overlap and make the misstake. Can you tell me how i can do the thinh i ask above?